# I have installed Magento CE on my private server, dont know how to setup email

Tags: email, smtp

I have installed Magento on `herbrishi.life`  how can I send and retrieve automatic email from my email address `info@herbrishi.life` which I got from gsuit.

Answer (score 0):

You may go through the links.........

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-set-up-outgoing-smtp-email-for-magento.html